# VirtoCommerce Deployment Debugging

Tags: virtocommerce

Having trouble when the store displays the "Under Maintenance" page when running in Azure.

I have yet to find any logging that helps diagnose what problem is.

I've configured Application Insights for the platform and that logging is working. Tried to configure the storefront for Application Insights logging but have yet to get that working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see real error on storefront you should change this line **customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" -> "Off"** in web.config.

```
  <customErrors mode="Off" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/ServerMaintenance.aspx" />
```